# How to open link-formated URLs in browser from org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I am using terminal based emacs. When I mouse click while `CMD` is pressed, clicked links are opened in my default browser.

In `org-mode`, when I click into URL(https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) it opens in my browser:

```
[GNU Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)
```

But instead when I do using https://orgmode.org/manual/Link-Format.html:

```
[[https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/][GNU Emacs]]

==> converted into 

GNU Emacs
```

And when I clicked into `GNU Emacs` it does not open in the browser. Would it be possible to force emacs to open link format URL in the browser using org-mode?

Comment: If you say `C-h c` and then click the primary button on the the link, what does it say about the function that that is bound to? And is the buffer's major mode `Org` or is it something else?

Comment: FWIW, in my case `<down-mouse-1>` translates to `<mouse-2>` which is bound to `org-open-at-mouse`: that opens the link in my browser. If `mouse-1` (i.e. left-click on RH mice) does not work, try `<mouse-2>` (i.e. middle-click). Also try RET on the link: it's bound to `org-open-at-point` in my case, because I have enabled `org-return-follows-link`. But I don't think I have changed any settings wrt the mouse.

Comment: @Nick buffer major mode is `Org`.  When it says `Describe the following key, mouse click, or menu item:` I click but nothing happens.

Comment: I can click into link here `[[GccEmacs][https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GccEmacs]]` but I cannot on the link here `[[https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GccEmacs][GccEmacs]]`

Comment: Try `ESC ESC : (load-library 'org-mouse)` and see if that fixes the mouse bindings.

Comment: I am having following error: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp org-mouse)`

Comment: @alper, if you place the point on that link and then ```C-c C-o``` will open it? (just for checking an alternate method)

Comment: Yes `C-c C-o`  opens it! But if I am using emacs in remote connected node using ssh it does not open it in my default browser

Comment: Sorry, it should be `(load-library "org-mouse")` - but I no longer think it's going to resolve your problem: I don't understand what you are doing well enough to suggest anything.

Comment: In markdown mode when I do `cmd+click` to a url link it opens it on my browser same works on the org-mode as well. But when `[[url][name]]`, which converted into just underlines `name` in the org made and when I `cmd+click` into that, it does not open it in my browser

Comment: So to go back to my first comment, what does Emacs say when you type `C-h c` and then `cmd+click` on the Org mode link? What happens if you do the same but just click, instead of `cmd+click`?

Comment: `Emacs` say nothing, seems like it does not detect `cmd+click` :-(